# I keep getting None returned from my python program

Tags: python

The code is as followed

```
# Cristmas Quiz
import time
from time import *

score = 1
quiz_q = [ 
        'how many turtle doves', 
        'how many French Hens',
        'how many gold rings', 
        'how many Lords a leaping?'
        ]

quiz_a = [2,3,5,10]

for n in range(4):
    question = input(print(quiz_q[n]))
    if quiz_a[n] == question:
        score += 1
    else:
        print("your score was ",score-1)
        time.sleep(5)
        quit()
```

which returns this:

```
how many turtle doves
None
```

I had a look around, but all the other qustion seemed to be refering about functions and the use of return vs print()

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't put `print` inside your `input()`. Just put `input(quiz_q[n])`. `print` returns `None`.

Comment: You are calling the `print` function, which outputs the text, then returns `None`. This is then passed to the `input` function, which outputs that and then waits for input.

Comment: It's important to show the full exception, because that would have told you which line it was coming from, and help you debug. But it has to be `input(print(quiz_q[n]))`. In future please paste the full exception.

Comment: @Kendas stick that in an answer and claim the prize

Comment: I'd make use of an editor that can check the syntax of your code, the linter would've found the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I'm reformatting my comment as an answer. I will attempt to elaborate on my explanation.

You are calling the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function, which outputs the text, then returns `None`. This may not be intuitive, but `None` is returned from any function that doesn't return anything else.

The `None` is then passed to the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function as a parameter, which transforms it into text, outputs that and then waits for input.

Answer (score 0):

The "input()" call should only take a string as an argument, not a print function:

```
for n in range(4):
    question = input(quiz_q[n])
    # ...
```